# Most efficient way to store and manipulate an array of timestamps in python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm designing a latency-sensitive application in python in which I will have several arrays of timestamps.  I am trying to count the number of occurrences of an event in the last 1,5,25,50, and 100 seconds, so 5 arrays in total.  I plan to append these arrays with the time of the event whenever it occurs.  Then in a separate thread, I will be removing values that are older than the past 1,5,25,50, or 100 seconds.

I expect to usually have less than 1000 occurrences per 100 seconds, but the theoretical maximum is 10,000 per 100 seconds.  I was planning to use a basic array of datetime objects, but I'm interested in learning what data structures are faster for this.  At first, I was considering a pandas dataframe but this proved to be far too slow.  I know about numpy arrays and using time.time() instead, but I imagine there are other ways that may be even more efficient.  Would love to hear what way of doing this will be the most computationally efficient from someone who is an expert in python.

Answer (score 2):

10-100 occurrences per second is nothing really. Simply using a list should be pretty fast. I would probably go with 1 list only. Using 5 collections in this case seems like an overkill and not worth it really.

One thing is the *write* performance, another thing is the *read* performance. Unless you need to have like a million reads per second, you should be fine with just looping over the list and counting the values in there.

One more tip: you would probably want to store the timestamps as numbers (Unix timestamp, seconds since 1970-01-01). And when you do the reading, do not get the current timestamp for every comparison. First get the current timestamp, save it into a local variable and then compare with that local variable. Like this:

```
curr_time = time.time()
for t in times:
    sec_ago = t - curr_time
    ...
```

Even though `CPython` is *relatively* slow when it comes to simple loops, comparisons, etc., performance should still be pretty good for your case, I guess. But if you really need extreme performance, you might consider implementing something more "native" in `C`, `Rust`, `Cython`, etc.

Try it!

Answer (score 0):

A [priority queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) (`heapq`) would let you keep timestamps in order, as threads finish execution. Heap insertion is `O(log(n))`. Removing oldest items from a sorted heap can be done by using a dictionary for a `O(1)` or constant time lookup.

If you use an array and just append timestamps as threads finish execution, you'd have to periodically lock the array from append operations, and then resort (`O(nlog(n))`) to remove oldest items. This might be simpler, conceptually, but take longer to run overall. Especially if you do this thousands or millions of times.

Using `timeit` with any approach is a good way to profile insertion, lookup, and deletion of whatever data structures you use.

Comment: Depending on his exact case, `heapq` might actually be slower than a simple list. Especially if he reads less often than he writes. Probably both solution should be fast enough, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach.

If you keep timestamps as integers (seconds from epoch), then you can directly use an array of size `2^31 - 1 - minimum_timestamp` as a [perfect hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).

Using an array with a perfect hash function is memory efficient, requiring only `O(n)` space. It is fast, requiring only `O(1)` constant time for insertion (writing) and querying (reading).

The value of `minimum_timestamp` is the minimum timestamp for which you need to track events. This would typically be whatever the current time is, unless you need to track events further back in the past.

The value of `2^31 - 1` is used here because that is the maximum value of [seconds from epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), so this solution would [work at least until 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), in the worst-case scenario where `minimum_timestamp` is zero, i.e. as far back as 1970.

All elements of this array are initialized to `0` and correspond to the number of events observed.

Every index into the array corresponds to a time point after `minimum_timestamp`.

When an event occurs at time point `n` (zero-indexed, in units of seconds from epoch), the array at index `n` is incremented by one, by subtracting `2^31 - 1 - n` to get the index to increment.

You could keep a `current_timestamp` value, where `current_timestamp > minimum_timestamp + 100`. To read the last 1, 5, 25, 50, and 100 seconds of data, you need only subtract from `current_timestamp` those values, to get the required index to read into the array.

As your threads work through processing events, you would periodically update `current_timestamp` as you read out or query the array.

To prevent race conditions, you need only lock updates to the portion of the array before `current_timestamp`, not the entire array. Threads can update event counts after this time point. This reduces the cost of locking.

This is not Python-specific, though you could use Cython to manage the underlying data and lookups, if you want the best performance out of a Python-based approach.

Adding to the end of a Python list (not an array, strictly speaking, but it can work as one) is relatively cheap, except when lists that grow past their capacity need resizing. This involves allocation of another larger chunk of memory and copying of data from an old list to new. Sorting lists for querying is also expensive. Locking them from thread access is expensive.

A perfect hash function on a real array (via Cython pointer, `array`, or `numpy`) will help you avoid sorting, if you can rethink your data in terms of unique indices into a pre-allocated array. Locking will be limited to a small subrange of indices into the array.

One potential downside, as hinted in comments, is that this approach generally limits measurement of events to per-second resolution. If this resolution is sufficient, the aforementioned approach will work well. If not, other solutions would need to be investigated.

Comment: If the OP expects events at rates up to 100 per sec, 1 sec precision seems a bit low? Or did I miss something in the concept?

Comment: It is not clear to me from the question what resolution is required. This does not appear to be specified. It sounds like multiple events can occur per second, up to a maximum of 10k per 100 seconds. If per-second resolution is sufficient for measurement, then this approach should work and will likely be among the more efficient and fast ways to store and query these data.